# Usar función anónima dentro de otra función en PHP

Tags: php, funcion

Debo crear una función que reciba por parámetro un string y que devuelva una función anónima que reciba otro string para que devuelva un string final con el prefijo de la primera.

```
$prefijo = "nano";
$word = "segundo";
```

Al llamar a la primera función me tendría que dar como resultado: `nanosegundo` (un string)

```
$prefijo = "nano";
$word = "segundo";
function prefijos($prefijo){
    $func = function ($string, $prefijo) {
        $r = $prefijo.$string;
        return $r;
    };
    // return $func;
    // return $r;
}
echo 'Resultado: '.prefijos($word);
```

El problema es que parece no puedo acceder de ninguna manera a `$r` con la respuesta final :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quiero que vean esta solución, la verdad no se si la lógica iría por ahí. Mi duda es por ejemplo si en vez del prefijo "nano" quiero que sea "multi", entonces como le puedo meter ese parámetro a la función desde fuera? no se si se entiende mi duda?

PD: Así, si que imprime lo que en teoría se necesita

```
$word = "segundo";
function prefijos($word){
    $prefijo = "nano";
    $func = function($prefijo) use ($word) {
        $r = $prefijo.$word;
        return $r;
    };
    return $func($prefijo); // Acá hago la llamado con el parámetro prefijo
}
echo 'Resultado: '.prefijos($word); // Resultado: nanosegundo
```

Answer (score 3):

En tu código hay 2 problemas: No le pasas todos los parámetros necesarios y tampoco devolviendo la función interna.

Entonces se puede arreglar:

```
$prefijo = "nano";
$word = "segundo";

function prefijos($prefijo, $word){
    $func = function ($prefijo, $string) {
        $r = $prefijo.$string;
        return $r;
    };
    return $func($prefijo, $word);
}

echo 'Resultado: '.prefijos($prefijo, $word); // <-- Son 2 parámetros
```

Otra forma es que la función interna use los parámetros de su contexto padre, en este caso, la función `prefijos`.

```
function prefijos($prefijo, $word){
    $func = function() use ($prefijo, $word) {
        $r = $prefijo.$word;
        return $r;
    };
    return $func();
}
```

Finalmente en PHP 7.4 o superior, se implementaron las [funciones flecha](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arrow.php) (arrow functions). Por lo que se puede escribir algo como:

```
function prefijos($prefijo, $word) {
    $func = fn($p, $w) => $p.$w;
    return $func($prefijo, $word);
}
```

Las funciones flecha de por sí están en el mismo contexto del padre, así que la función anterior se puede reescribir a:

```
function prefijos($prefijo, $word) {
    $func = fn() => $prefijo.$word;
    return $func();
}
```

Comment: Pero esta llamando a la función con dos argumentos, cuando a la primera función se le debe pasar un argumento y a la segunda otro. Porque así es fácil hacer algo como:
$prefijo = "nano";
 $word = "segundo";
 function prefijos($prefijo, $word){
     // $func = function ($prefijo, $string) {
         $r = $prefijo.$word;
         return $r;
     // };
     // return $func($prefijo, $word);
 }
 echo 'Resultado: '.prefijos($prefijo,$word);

Answer (score 1):

No puedes acceder a r porque nunca lo regresas, para poder utilizarlo debes de regresar r, otra cosa para utilizar la variable $prefijo tienes que hacer el uso de use en la segunda funcion.

```
function prefijos($prefijo){
return function ($string) use ($prefijo){
    $r = $prefijo.$string;
    return $r;
};
```

Comment: Algo así es como se supone debe quedar, pero completé su código y no daba la respuesta correcta por el error: Uncaught Error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string, cuando hacia la llamada a la función

Comment: Lo debes de llamar prefijos('palabra')('aopciones') y cuando se hace echo imprimiria algo asi palabra.aopciones